# localhost:1972 shown in NoScript

Tags: noscript

I can see that there is a blocked script for "localhost:1972" in NoScript for a webpage (not public).

But if I right click, "save as" the webpage, then I do a "grep -r 1972" in its files, it doesn't give anything!

How can I find where the localhost:1972 is on the webpage?

Answer (score 3):

You need to read up on the structure and interpretation of URLs. See [A Guide to URLs](https://www.livinginternet.com/w/ww_addr_urlguide.htm). The "1972" of your question is referring to the [port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking)); when you save the web page to your local disk, the 1972 is not part of the data being saved.

You may think of a URL as being like a street address, and a port number as an instruction to go to a specific door. Normally, if you're told to go to an address, you knock on the front door (or ring the doorbell); occasionally, you might be told "... and go to the side door and ring the top bell". That's like going to a non-standard port for the protocol.

Comment: I think the askers point is that they don't know where that port number was specified.

Comment: @jdwolf - I'll allow that as a possibility, but without access to the non-public webpage, there's no way to troubleshoot further. If, for example, the calling webpage is also on 'localhost:1972', a relative reference in the `a href=` tag would not give a positive result for the `grep`, but NoScript would still catch the script.